# Python/CPLEX "inconsistent arguments" error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, constraints, linear-programming, cplex

I am trying to solve the following simple LP problem using CPLEX in Jupyter based Python and get the following error.

Can anybody please help to interpret the error. The LP problem has 6 vars and 3 constraints. I have checked the dimensions of lists defined and they're consistent with the size of the problem.

```
Maximize {obj: - 28.44 x1 - 27.38 x2 - 26.44 x3 - 25.38 x4 - 26.44 x5
- 25.38 x6} 
Subject To 
 c1:   x1 + x2 = 0
 c2:   x3 + x4 = 0
 c3:   x5 + x6 = 0
Bounds
    -2.1 <= x1 <= 2.1
    -2.1 <= x2 <= 2.1
    -2.1 <= x3 <= 2.1
    -2.1 <= x4 <= 2.1
    -2.1 <= x5 <= 2.1
    -2.1 <= x6 <= 2.1
```

---

```
import cplex
from cplex.exceptions import CplexError
import sys

my_obj = [-28.44, -27.38, -26.44, -25.38, -26.44, -25.38]
my_ub =  [2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1]
my_lb  = [-2.1, -2.1, -2.1, -2.1, -2.1, -2.1]
my_rhs = [0,0,0]
my_sense    = "EE"
rows = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
cols = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
vals = [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]

my_prob = cplex.Cplex()
my_prob.objective.set_sense(my_prob.objective.sense.maximize)
my_prob.linear_constraints.add(rhs = my_rhs, senses = my_sense, names = [])
my_prob.variables.add(obj = my_obj, ub = my_ub, lb = my_lb, names = [])
my_prob.linear_constraints.set_coefficients(zip(rows, cols, vals))
my_prob.solve()
```

Comment: My guess: `my_sense` is shorter than `my_rhs`

Comment: Yes, I noticed that after posting. Thanks!!

Comment: Too bad Cplex does not give a better error message. I would like to see which arguments were not consistent and why. That would have prevented this question altogether. Programmers do not pay enough attention writing informative error messages.

Comment: Agree. looks like CPLEX only creates a very general "inconsistent argument" whenever the sizes of any vectors called are not consistent. The users have to  check the length of the vectors themselves to figure out...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this question has already been answered in the comments. In short, the lengths of `my_sense` and `my_rhs` are different. The long answer is below.

When we run your script, we see a traceback like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "20200106.py", line 16, in <module>
    my_prob.linear_constraints.add(rhs = my_rhs, senses = my_sense, names = [])
  File "/home/rkersh/virtualenv/3.6/cplex/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/cplex/_internal/_subinterfaces.py", line 1259, in add
    lin_expr, senses, rhs, range_values, names)
  File "/home/rkersh/virtualenv/3.6/cplex/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/cplex/_internal/_baseinterface.py", line 41, in _add_iter
    addfun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rkersh/virtualenv/3.6/cplex/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/cplex/_internal/_subinterfaces.py", line 1181, in _add
    validate_arg_lengths(arg_list)
  File "/home/rkersh/virtualenv/3.6/cplex/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/cplex/_internal/_aux_functions.py", line 99, in validate_arg_lengths
    raise CplexError("inconsistent arguments" + extra_msg)
cplex.exceptions.errors.CplexError: inconsistent arguments
```

From the first line, we know the line where the problem came from:

```
my_prob.linear_constraints.add(rhs = my_rhs, senses = my_sense, names = [])
```

And from the last line, we know why:

```
cplex.exceptions.errors.CplexError: inconsistent arguments
```

Also, the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex._internal._subinterfaces.LinearConstraintInterface-class.html#add) for this method states:

> If more than one argument is specified, all arguments must have the
>   same length.

Well, what the documentation says is not entirely true. As done in your script, the user can provide empty lists for some arguments and omit optional arguments.

As to whether the error message could have been better. CPLEX can't easily determine which arguments are wrong per se (the user could provide a list that is too long, too short, or both). Rather, it can only point out that the arguments have inconsistent lengths or not. Perhaps, the error message could be improved by saying "inconsistent argument lengths". It's already clear from the Traceback which arguments are in question, but the argument names could be included too, like so: "inconsistent argument lengths: len_expr, senses, rhs, range_values, names". Would that have helped?

Comment: I think it would. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @Sam: Thanks for the feedback. I'll create a new issue for this error message improvement.